# Powershell script to reset TPMLockout

Tags: powershell-ise, tpm

We have Windows 7 Enterprise laptops with TPM chips. We have deployed Bitlocker to these laptops. What I'm trying to accomplish is to write a PowerShell script to look up the msTPM-OwnerInformation value for a specific computer in AD. I want it to then take that value and reset the TPMLockout.

Right now we have to go into the TPM console and click reset and specify the XML file that contains that value.

I have started on a script, but it's not doing what I want it to do as I'm very new to PowerShell.

Comment: Anyone? Just hoping to get some help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file named "Get_msTPM-OwnerInformation.ps1"
and paste the following text to it.

Change the Part 'DOMAIN/OU' to your needs.
This should read you all the Information you need out of the AD

```
#----------------------Start----------------------------------------------------------------
#Custom variables
$CsvFilePath = "C:\Temp\BitLockerComputerReport.csv"

#Create array to hold computer information
$export = @()

#Export computers not Bitlocker-enabled to a CSV-file
#$BitLockerEnabled = Get-QADObject -SizeLimit 0 -IncludedProperties cn,Name,ParentContainer,msFVE-RecoveryPassword | Where-Object {$_.type -eq “msFVE-RecoveryInformation”} | Foreach-Object {
$BitLockerEnabled = Get-QADObject -SearchRoot 'DOMAIN/OU' -SizeLimit 0 -IncludedProperties cn,Name,ParentContainer,msFVE-RecoveryPassword | Where-Object {$_.type -eq “msFVE-RecoveryInformation”} | Foreach-Object {


#Get PasswordID
$_.cn -match “(?<={).*(?=})"

#Create custom object for each computer
$computerobj = New-Object -TypeName psobject

#Add information to custom object
$computerobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value (Split-Path -Path $_.ParentContainer -Leaf)
$computerobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PasswordID -Value $matches[0]
$computerobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "msFVE-RecoveryPassword" -Value $_."msFVE-RecoveryPassword"
$computerobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "msTPM-OwnerInformation" -Value (Get-QADComputer -IncludedProperties "msTPM-OwnerInformation" -Name (Split-Path -Path $_.ParentContainer -Leaf))."msTPM-OwnerInformation"

$export += $computerobj
}

#Export the array with computerinformation to the user-specified path
$export | Export-Csv -Path $CsvFilePath -NoTypeInformation
#------------------------End--------------------------------------------------------------
```